# how to get status code from success block I am using AFHTTPSessionManager?

Tags: objective-c, afnetworking, afnetworking-3, afhttpsessionmanager

I am unable to handle the status code from success block. Please give me suggestion how to handle the 204 No Content message[image]

I amusing AFHTTPSessionManager of AfNetworking 
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: `task.response.statusCode`?

Comment: How can I get status code from success block ?

Comment: I want to get the status code: 204 from success block

Comment: i got the answer                                                                  NSHTTPURLResponse* r = (NSHTTPURLResponse*)task.response;
            NSLog(@"response %ld",(long)[r statusCode]);

Comment: So wasn't that my answer from the beginning?

Comment: yes, larme thank you for reply